# How can I get rid of "\n" from string in c?

Tags: c, string

I use function ascitime in C

```
   #include <time.h>
    char *asctime(const struct tm *timeptr);

    returns something like:
    Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973\n\0
```

It returns this "string"(resp. char *):

> Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973\n\0

How can I rid of "\n" from this string? I don't want nextline which cause "\n".
Thx

Comment: Title implies a general solution is needed "rid of “\n” from string", yet sample code and accepted answer is for a narrow condition `asctime()`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The other answers seem overcomplicated. Your case is simple because you know the unwanted character is the last one in the string.

```
char *foo = asctime();
foo[strlen(foo) - 1] = 0;
```

This nulls the last character (the \n).

Comment: Only works for a \n as the second to last character not any arbitrary \n character

Comment: @blueshift yes, it's really all I need cause I use it like timestamp before messages in server logs. Thx a lot ;-)

Answer (score 5):

After Accept Answer

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628718/2410359) seems over complicated.  `asctime()` returns a pointer to a *fixed* sized array of 26 in the form:

```
> Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973\n\0 
> 0123456789012345678901234455

char *timetext = asctime(some_timeptr);
timetext[24] = '\0';   // being brave (and foolish) with no error checking
```

---

The general solution to removing a potential (trailing) `'\n'` that is more resistant to unusual strings would be:

```
char *some_string = foo();

char *p = strchr(str, '\n');  // finds first, if any, \n
if (p != NULL) *p = '\0';

// or

size_t len = strlen(str);
if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') str[--len] = '\0';

// or
str[strcspn(str,"\n")] = '\0';
```

`str[strlen(str) - 1]` is not safe until first establishing `strlen(str) > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can't make it return the string without the newline. You need to just strip off the `\n` with some basic looping.

```
int i;

for(i = 0;; i++) {
  if(str[i] == '\n') {
    str[i] = '\0';
    break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can read the information manually from the `tm struct`.

Comment: This only works if there aren't any characters after the '\n' that have to be retained.

Comment: No point looping twice. Better doing this without the strlen, or what blueshift suggests would perhaps be even better.

Comment: No need to loop, you know the \n is the last character.

Answer (score 1):

why not use printf with a maximum width? seeing as you call printf anyway...

```
static void debug_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list arglist;

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

      time ( &rawtime );
      timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

      printf ( "%.24s: ", asctime (timeinfo) );

    va_start( arglist, format );
    vprintf( format, arglist );
    va_end( arglist );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strtok` to split the string on `"\n"` and the concatenate the tokens.

Comment: I know that it's a `char *` in this case but that's because the strtok expects a `const char *` as an argument. The `'\n'` character will not work as an argument. But I'll remove the word character to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it with 1 line of code:

```
printf("The time is: %s.", strtok(asctime(timeinfo), "\n"));
```